# Sympy matrix linear algebra modulo p

Tags: math, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra

Does Sympy's matrix linear algebra functionality work with matrices over a finite field F_p (p prime)? How can you set up sympy linear algebra to work over this field and do calculations?

Answer (score 1):

In SymPy you can do it like this:

```
In [36]: from sympy import *

In [37]: from sympy.polys.matrices import DomainMatrix

In [38]: F = GF(7)

In [39]: M = DomainMatrix([[F(1), F(2)], [F(3), F(4)]], (2, 2), F)

In [40]: M
Out[40]: DomainMatrix([[1 mod 7, 2 mod 7], [3 mod 7, 4 mod 7]], (2, 2), GF(7))

In [41]: M**10
Out[41]: DomainMatrix([[0 mod 7, 1 mod 7], [5 mod 7, 5 mod 7]], (2, 2), GF(7))

In [42]: M.inv()
Out[42]: DomainMatrix([[5 mod 7, 1 mod 7], [5 mod 7, 3 mod 7]], (2, 2), GF(7))
```

Comment: It looks like `from sympy import *` should really be `from sympy import GF`!